# ajax event not updating the button to enable

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

am using primefaces4.0,tomcat6 for my application.
I have a table with checkboxes  in a dialog box with a submit button.
And the button is disabled if no check box is selcted.
Upon selecting checkbox i have to enable the submit button.
But after selection the submit button is nt getting enabled.

Here is my code

```
<p:dataTable value="#{product.unsubscribedLicenseTypes}"
        selection="#{product.selectedLicense}"
        widgetVar="licenseTable" paginatorPosition="bottom"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" var="licType" paginator="true"
        currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {startRecord}-{endRecord} out of {totalRecords}"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}  {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        pageLinks="0" rows="5" rowKey="#{licType.id}">
    <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" update="@(#submitBtn)" />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="@(#submitBtn)" onstart="alert('row select')" onerror="alert('err')" onsuccess="alert('Success')"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="@(#submitBtn)" />
    <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" update="@(#submitBtn)" />
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" update="@(#submitBtn)" />
</p:dataTable>

<p:commandButton  value="#{msg['button.submit']}" id="submitBtn"
    styleClass="submitFormButton" oncomplete="alert('hi');dlg.hide()"
    action="#{product.addLicenseTypeToProduct}" 
    disabled="#{fn:length(product.selectedLicense) eq 0}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update="@(#submitBtn)"  update="submitBtn"
```

change your update like i mentioned..

Comment: Thanks for ur reply vicky, i tried that also but got this error            Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with expression "submitBtn" referenced from "j_idt62:j_idt121".

Answer (score 0):

First of all look how your generated code looks like in browser. I bet your your buttons ID looks something like that `j_idt62:submitBtn`, this is because your `<h:form>` does not have an id. `<h:form>` among some others is a naming container and it appends own Id to its children components, so if you gave your form id like so `<h:form id="form">` your button would look like `<button id="form:submitBtn" >`. Vicky mentioned using relative path to your button, this would work if the button and the component calling update upon it could find each other since they can not you have to use absolute path to your button (provided you ided the form).

```
<p:ajax update=":form:submitBtn" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
<p:commandButton widgetVar="var" ... />
```

and

```
... update="@widgetVar(var)"
```